# I am using vlookup across 2 spreadsheets. The formula appears to be correct, but the value is not returning, only the formula displays

Tags: excel

I am using 2 spreadsheets. Sheet1 -Return Codes needs the values from Sheet 2- GL Interfaces. I am trying to match with column 1 on sheet 1 to sheet 2 in order to bring back the correct Name associated with an application ID.

The formula displays in the cell instead of the value replacing the formula:
`=VLOOKUP(A2,'GL Interfaces'!A2:F61,2,False)`.  What is wrong with my formula for this simple lookup?

1. I click in the column where I want the value to return to.
2. Click Formula | select Vlookup.
3. Click on A2 (the column with the application numbers) on sheet 1
4. Go to second sheet and highlight array that I want to be searched.
5. Put in 2 as a column with the Names (col index num) that I want to be searched on the second sheet
6. Enter False for the last entry (Range_Lookup)
7. Enter and only the formal displays in the cell I want a Name to appear.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is the cell formatting maybe set to "Text"?

Comment: Also, press `CTRL+\`` to see if you also may have turned on "Show Formulas" by accident.  If you enter `=SUM(1,2)` in that same cell, does it show the formula, or `3`?

Answer (score 0):

```
=VLOOKUP(A2, 'GL Interfaces'!A2:F61, 2, false)
```

is a valid formula. make sure that the first column of the 2nd argument of vlookup is the one that contains the value from the first argument of vlookup. in other words: `A2` needs to be found in A column of sheet `GL Interfaces` and if there is a row with a match, then return value from B column of `GL Interfaces` sheet